# In git when adding files, a number of files appear as different, what does the symbol @ mean when ls in terminal?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, ls, iterm2

In git when adding files, a number of files appear as different, what does the symbol @ mean when ls in terminal?

For example, when running ls -lh, what does the @ symbol denote? This is run on MacOS - item2 bash, if that makes any difference.

the following is the output of two files but one with an @ behind it. permissions are similar and both are files in the same directory :

```
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff    10K 10 Jan 10:10 README.fileone.md
-rw-r--r--@ 1 me  staff    10K 11 Jan 10:10 README.filetwo.md
```

and the recommended way(s)/commands to change these files.

**edit**

thanks for answers below.

**summary of answer**

use ***xattr*** to view or edit the file

```
$xattr -c filename.xxx     # deletes ALL extended attributes from file 
$xattr -l filename.xxx     # views attributes from file
```

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106642/what-does-the-at-symbol-mean-on-osx-ls/106643

Comment: thanks for note. btw how is this off topic. note - "directly involve tools used primarily for programming". "ls" is a tool .. file management (i.e. inclusive of file permissions) is perhaps one of the most basic requirements in programming?

Comment: No it isn't, because it is also relevant when you're not programming, but just using the OS, thus it fails the "tools **primarily used for** programming" test.

Comment: alot of IDE depends on tools that are multifaceted. so going down that route will render almost all questions not qualified in stackoverflow. Do a search and you can find ftp tools.. ssh questions and lots more on overflow... but fine if it isnt appropriate here.. please suggest and move this question. I did a search and took ages to not find an appropriate answer, thus kindly added it here for future devs to resolve their issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file has [extended attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes). With [xattr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/19) command-line utility you can inspect and modify them.